# Include fxml file to executable jar

Tags: java, javafx, jar, build

i'm trying to create a jar file but when i attempt to run it i'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.`

This is how it is loaded it in my code:

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/view/MainView.fxml"));
```

jar file is built using intellij idea : Project Structure -> Artifacts

**Solved**

I've managed to solve it with maven by adding

```
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

and maven-assembly-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building your project via your IDE isn't a good idea. It changes the directory structure of your project, so your relative path to the fxml file isn't correct anymore. You should get rid of that problem if you build your project with Maven. Then add the `maven-compiler-plugin` to your generated pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
    </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Comment: (shameless advertizing) And regarding JavaFX, it would help to use the javafx-maven-plugin aswell ;) makes it easier to bundle the app for distribution